# parallel async Mongoose queries || eval(return) SyntaxError : Illegal return statement

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a lot of requests to Mongo with Mongoose. I'd like them to be parallel and async. I don't know how many I might have to query so I created this helper function. It works fine, although I'm not sure about my eval usage. The problem is the eval(return${returnStr}) giving me the SyntaxError.

```js
const batchRetrieve = async (query, models) => {
  models.forEach((model, i) => {
    eval(`task${i} = ${model}.findOne(query)`);
  });
  let str = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
    str.push(`res${i}: await task${i}`);
  }

  const joinedStr = Array.prototype.join.call(str, ', '); //output is 'res0: await task0, res1: await task1'

  //    return { res0: await task0, res1: await task1 }; works fine 
  eval(`return { ${joinedStr} };`);
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `eval()` there anyway?  Just `return joinedStr;` should be all you need.

Comment: (Also if you're getting a syntax error I'd hardly say that it "works fine".)

Comment: And `str` is an array so you can just use `str.join(', ')`, no reason to explicitly go to the Array prototype like that.

Comment: "And str is an array so you can just use str.join(', '), no reason to explicitly go to the Array prototype like that. " : It doesn't do it -> str.join() is not a function.

"Also if you're getting a syntax error I'd hardly say that it "works fine". : It does when I call the comment above the eval();

"Why would you want to use eval() there anyway? Just return joinedStr; should be all you need. " -> Javascript doesn't work that way, the function will return 'res0: await task0, res1: await task1' instead of the document.

@Pointy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: If you're using `eval`, you're doing it wrong. Try this:

```
const batchRetrieve = async (query, models) => {
  const promises = [];
  models.forEach(model => {
    promises.push(model.findOne(query));
  });

  const results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
    results.push(await promises[i]);
  }

  return results;
};
```

Comment: I do understand the first part, I had something similar in the beginning, but I switched it out to eval because of a weird error. 
I don't think I understand why the second part works, but this is clearly way better than whatever garbage i produced :)

Comment: What do you not understand about the second part?

Comment: I'm mostly not sure when the model.findOne(query) functions are fired. 
I always assumed that when I instantiated them with task1 = model1.findOne(query); and the return then waited for them to finish before returning. Before that I tried task1 = await model .... and that would make them run in series.
I guess they are actually fired inside the return.
Also the return executes stuff, mind blown.
Thanks again for your help :) 
@David Knipe

Comment: No, the requests are sent when `model.findOne` is called. It runs up to `await`, then waits for the first promise to resolve. And when I say "waits", I mean it's asynchronous - other stuff might run while it's waiting. The resolved value is pushed into the array. Then it goes through the loop again and waits for the second promise (but this time it might not take very long if this promise resolved before the first one). They run in parallel because `model.findOne` and `await` are in separate loops. Eventually, the promise returned by the call to `batchRetrieve` resolves to `results`.

Comment: This makes so much more sense. Thank you so much !
Would it make sense to generalize batchRetrieve even more into something like parrallelAsync = async (function (e.g. like .findOne(), .save()) , models )? or should I just recreate this as a saveBatch :)?

Comment: You could do `const batchDo = (doOne) => async (query, models) => { ... promises.push(doOne(model, query)); ... }; const batchRetrieve = batchDo((model, query) => model.findOne(query));`. You can also make it more concise with `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0):

replacing the eval(`return { ${joinedStr} };`); with

```js
  return eval(`(async () => {
        return { ${joinedStr} }
    })();`);
```

resolves my issue.